# VS code extensions for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-platform-channel

I want to write platform specific code for **Android** using **Java** but cannot find suitable extensions for it in **Visual Studio Code**. I installed the recommended extensions for Java but it is not working properly, like it is not predicting any android specific stuff.

Is there a way to do it the way it works in Android Studio?

Comment: There's some discussion about this at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25369.

Comment: So basically there are no **Stable** plugin for this. Guess I will just have to use Android Studio.